# Unable to use LocalCustomProperties["_Sys_Nav_TargetUrl"] inside my event receiver . Exception "The given key was not present in the dictionary. "

Tags: development, event-receivers, 2016, farm-solution, managed-navigation

I am working on an Enterprise wiki site collection inside `SharePoint Server 2016`. and i wrote the following event receiver which get fired when an item is updated, here is part of my event receiver which is causing the issue:-

```
TermSet ts = g.TermSets[termsetname.Trim()];
foreach (Term t56 in ts.Terms)
          {
              string targetPageURL = t56.LocalCustomProperties["_Sys_Nav_TargetUrl"]
```

now the above is raising the following exception :-

> The given key was not present in the dictionary.

now i remember i use to do this inside my sharepoint 2013 and it is working well. but not sure if inside sharepoint 2016 i can not use `LocalCustomProperties["_Sys_Nav_TargetUrl"]` to get the target page for my navigation term ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `_Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl` key to fetch the value of url.

So, your code would be:

```
TermSet ts = g.TermSets[termsetname.Trim()];
foreach (Term t56 in ts.Terms)
{
     string targetPageURL = t56.LocalCustomProperties["_Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl"];
```

Dont remember about SP 2013, but in case of SP Online and 2016, we have used `_Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl` in the code only and it fetches the url associated with the term.

**Update** - In case you have configured the term to use `Term Driven Page with Friendly URL`, then `_Sys_Nav_TargetUrl` will work. If you have configured the term to use `Simple Link or Header`, then you will need to use `_Sys_Nav_SimpleLinkUrl` property.